# How to show only data which are available in a row and column table? Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a row and column table. I would like to display only the data which are available. How shall I proceed?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really clear on your question, but if all you want to keep is the red box you can add that dimension to the filter shelf; or right click on the dimension and say "show filter"; or click on the value and select "keep only".

Other than that, Tableau *is* only displaying the data which is available.  Check out the documentation on [filtering](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Filter.

Drag [Receiver Zip] to the filter pane and select 'A1E' as the only value.

Then drag [Sender Zip] to the filter pane and select 'A1A' as the only value.

You will be left with a table that only has the value in your red outline.